# How to get Columns and Tables used from SQL statement

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ado.net

I need to get the columns and tables used in a query but I'm not finding an elegant way of doing it. I've search about it but can't find information that works to me. The query has this format

```sql
select TABLE1.Id, TABLE2.Name, TABLE3.Observations, TABLE3.Adress, --and more 70 fields
from TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4
```

Is there any Good Way of doing this two tasks?

Comment: That is not what `SqlCommand.Parameters` is for. The `SqlCommand.Parameters` object is a collection of *replacement parameters* for use within a query. I.e. `SELECT Plate, Brand FROM Car WHERE Plate = @Plate`, then you would add a `SqlParameter` to `SqlCommand.Parameters` with a name of `@Plate`, type of `NvarChar`, or `VarChar` or whatever it is, and a value of `ABC1234`. The `Sql` driver would replace `@Plate` in the query with a **Sql Safe** representation of `'ABC1234'`.

Comment: `SqlParameter`s are **input**, not **output**.

Comment: Do you also want the actual data or just the columns?

Comment: @Maarten There are output parameters too :) But it doesn't work the way OP expects.

Comment: Hello @DStanley I Want the Column names and the Table Names

Comment: @Nelssen You should rename and update the question with what you are actually asking so future users have an easier time finding the correct question and answer.

Comment: I don't know that you can actually pull back source table names?  You can certainly pull back column names though, by pulling for example the top 1 row, and iterating through the column names in the resulting data set.

Comment: Actually on second thought, you might be able to just utilize substring to extract the actual select statement, then do a split based on spaces...then look at each of these values and split again on . to have a set of table names and column names...

Comment: Hello @user2366842 that's What I'll do if I dont find any other way less heavier programmatically. thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that `SqlCommand.Parameters` is a series of `SqlParameter` objects that are to be replaced in the query with actual values. I.e. they are **input** parameters. They are used for the `SqlCommand` to replace with **SQL Safe** and **Compatible** representations of the included parameters. I.e. with your query, something like the following would suffice:

```
SqlCommand sql = new SqlCommand("SELECT TABLE1.Id, TABLE2.Name, TABLE3.Observations, TABLE3.Address FROM TABLE1, TABLE2, TABLE3, TABLE4 WHERE TABLE2.Name = @Name")
sql.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Name", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 32));
sql.Parameters["@Name"] = "Your Name";
```

The SQL driver would then replace `@Name` in the query with a **SQL Safe** representation of `'Your Name'`.

To do what you want, you would be required to parse the actual string and break it down into it's *tokens* or *statements*. This is a complex process for some statements.

Depending on what your requirements (for support of syntax) are, you could easily break the statement down by extracting everything between `SELECT` and `FROM` in this case, break the strings on commas, and then break further on periods to get table names and fields names.

Some sample code that should do what you want (untested at this moment):

```
// sql.CommandText can be replaced with the raw SQL Query String
string query = sql.CommandText;
string removeSelect = query.Substring(7); // Remove the SELECT and space
string removeAfterFrom = removeSelect.Substring(0, removeSelect.IndexOf(" FROM ")); // Remove the FROM
string[] columns = removeAfterFrom.Split(','); // Get each Column

List<string> tables = new List<string>();

for (int i = 0; i < columns.Length; i++)
{
    string[] columnName = columns[i].Split('.');
    if (columnName.Length > 1)
        if (!tables.Contains(columnName[0]))
            tables.Add(columnName[0].Trim());
}
```

Also, another note, this code could readily be modified to extract the table names from the `FROM` clause instead.

Essentially, your goal here is to create a rudimentary **SQL Parser** that can return certain values/objects from your SQL Statement. If it's always a `SELECT` statement, than this method will work on **all** variants except those that use a wildcard (`*`) column name, or those that use `TOP (n)`. If you have to support `TOP (n)` queries, you should add an appropriate filter. It will also **only** return table names that were included in the column name clause. (I.e. requires fully qualified names: `SELECT TABLE1.Name FROM TABLE1` instead of `SELECT Name FROM TABLE1`.

If you prefer to get **all** tables specified in the query (regardless if any columns are selected from them) you may use the following instead.

```
// sql.CommandText can be replaced with the raw SQL Query String
string query = sql.CommandText;
string removeSelect = query.Substring(7); // Remove the SELECT and space
string[] splitOnFrom = removeSelect.Split(new string[] { " FROM " }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string[] columns = splitOnFrom[0].Split(','); // Get each Column
string[] tables = splitOnFrom[1].Split(','); // Get each Table
```

The `columns` array will have all the **fully-qualified** column names, and the `tables` array will have all the **fully-qualified** table names.

Another sidebar on both methods: the `FROM` **term** (word) is **case-sensitive**. I.e. `From`, `from` will not work. If you wish to use the first method and make `from` case-insensitive, the following would work:

```
string removeAfterFrom = removeSelect.Substring(0, removeSelect.IndexOf(" FROM ", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
```

For the second, you would need to modify it a bit more, but it's not terribly difficult.

---

As far as I know, there is nothing built-in that has this functionality. (Though I'm sure a quick Google Search could prove me wrong.)

Comment: Hello EBrown, Thanks for the input! As it involves to create a rudimentar SQL Parser that is very stuck to this kind of query. I just leaved this approach and adopted an other solution for my problem that does not require parsing the SQL Query! Many Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There tho ways I can think of right now.

First one is to actually execute the SQL statement in question (possibly wrap it in `begin tran`/`rollback tran`) and then extract column names from the `SqlDataReader`.

Second is to hand-roll a rudimentary parser. This can be pretty simple, especially if all you have to support is the `select a.b, c, d.e from ...` syntax.